# Referencing model from one model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my Schema.rb

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170617073406) do

  create_table "actions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "post_id"
    t.datetime "timestamp"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "user_id"
    t.datetime "last_activity"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

These are my three model classes.

Action.rb

```
class Action < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    has_many :users, :foreign_key => 'user_user_id'
end
```

Post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :actions, :foreign_key => 'action_id'
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :actions, :foreign_key => 'action_id'
end
```

I am trying to add an instance of `Action` object into `Post` model object.

```
post = Post.find(post_id=post_id)
current_action = post.actions.find_or_create_by(name: "like")
```

It gives me the following error:
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: actions.action_id: SELECT "actions".* FROM "actions" WHERE "actions"."action_id" = ? AND "actions"."name" = ? LIMIT ?`

I am new to Ruby on Rails and come from Django background. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: one ting which seem incorrect is the first line of code. You are trying to fnd a Post with post_id. It looks recursive. Where do you get this post_id from ?

Comment: @user2507 what is an action? is this a "user action"? If so then your `Action` model should be `belongs_to :user` instead of `has_many :users`, and then your `User` model should have `has_many :actions`

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario The relationships are fine. I need them like that. Is there something wrong with the current relationship? Action needs to be related to the user as many to many as in my case one user object can have many action instances and each action instance can have many user instances.

Comment: @user2507 oh no, it's okay as long as you yourself intend it to be. I'll write an answer that will create migrations. hopefully this works for you.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I ran `rails db:migrate` after writing the relationships too. But I think we only need to run this command when we create a new model. Is that right?

Comment: @Maxence The `post` object gets initialized just fine. When I print it, it prints the object instance and I can reference all the model fields from it. Why does it look recursive to you?

Comment: creating a post_id field inside your Post model seems a bit strange. Usually when we have `something_id` is when we have a relationships between models and have to store the id of the model we refer to... We create those references inside the migration

Comment: @Maxence What will be the best way to change to type of ID for a given model from Integer to String, I looked up and found no easier way.

Comment: Following this, your action model should have a post_id field. When creating model, you should create a reference to parent model. that's why it's good to iterate model creation

Comment: Why do you want an index to be a string ? It is just a number...

Comment: @Maxence The ID I want to store is longer than Integer can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146942/discussion-between-maxence-and-user2507).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Action needs to be related to the user as many to many...

If you want a *many-to-many* association, you will need to use another table (i.e. a *join model*):

```
class Action < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    has_many :user_actions
    has_many :users, through: :user_actions
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_actions
    has_many :actions, through: :user_actions
end

class UserAction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :action
    belongs_to :user
end
```

> The ID I want to store is longer than Integer can do.

You can specify your own `id` in the migration and avoid adding an extra `action_id`:

```
class CreateActions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :actions, id: false do |t|
      t.string :id, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :actions, :id , unique: true
  end
end
```

With the above setup, you don't need to specify any `foreign_key` in `Post` either, *ActiveRecord* will use defaults (i.e. `action_id`):

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :actions
end
```

---

A note about associations and foreign keys (and why you got that error):

Whenever you create an association, the `foreign_key` must be created in the table with the `belongs_to` side, since *ActiveRecord* will look for that key there.

Even If you don't specify a `belongs_to`, a `has_many` reference to that table will still look for that `foreign_key`.

So, when you add

```
has_many :actions, :foreign_key => 'action_id'
```

you are telling *ActiveRecord* to look for `action_id` column in `actions` table, but that columns has not being created in `actions` table.

In the proposed solution, the foreign keys are on the *join table* model (i.e. UserActions), so you must create a migration to include them:

```
rails g migration CreateUserActions user:references action:references
```

Comment: So if I have two tables A and B, with M:N relation. I need to have another table C to properly associated them together?

Comment: @user2507 Exactly, you can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Comment: Yes, I am processig your solution. ROR has a confusing way of things.

Comment: This need of another table C, is it ROR specific? since when I worked with Django, I didn't need it.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer Gerry, what you said makes sense. I'll update my code and let you know if it works :)

Comment: @user2507 Well, no, its not _Rails_ specific, in any many-to-many relationship you need a third table to join them. I don't know _Django_, but maybe it creates that _C_ table automatically.

Comment: Hi Gerry, just one more thing, if I have two instances say `user` and `action` and I want to add `action` to the `user` list of many instances. How do I do that? I found that `.create` method is used for this purpose but suppose my instance is already created then what method do I use to add it?

Comment: @user2507 For that you will need to create a new `UserAction` object, like this: UserAction.create(user: user, action: action)` or `UserAction.create(user_id: user.id, action_id: action.id)`.

Comment: `add_index :actions, :id , unique: true` why do we need this line if we have already added the ID of type string in the newly created table?

Comment: @user2507 `t.string :id` adds a _regular_ column, that is, its neither indexed as a _primary key_ would be, nor has a `unique` constraint (to avoid duplicate `id`); so `add_index ...` creates that index and constraint.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

Run migrations in command line:

```
rails generate migration add_post_to_actions post:belongs_to
rake db:migrate
```

Then update:

```
class Action < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  # ...
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'post_id'
  has_many :actions
  # ...
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'user_id'
  # ...
end
```

### Explanation:

- 1st line would add `post_id` column to `actions` table, and then index it with foreign constraint
- The above migrations are independent of the contents of your current model files. You can even delete your models/action.rb or models/user.rb, and you'll see that the migrations would still even run without problems, because migrations only "do" stuff on the actual current database. The migration files also do not even care about whatever is written in your `schema.rb`, although it will update that `schema.rb` each time you run a migration (after the database has already been migrated/updated).

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks

Comment: Hey, it is still not working. I will update my question for the changes I have done.

Comment: Apart from the commands you mentioned, I also ran `rails generate migration add_user_to_actions user:has_many`. Please refer to my question as I had not posted the User model earlier.

Comment: Seems like you have a has_many x has_many relationship for two `actions` and `posts`. See Gerry's answer for a "join-table". You need this 3rd table so that you won't have to repeat data. i.e. you won't be repeating multiple rows of exactly the same columns values for `users` table. say your users table has `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, and `action_id` columns. This will repeat data: i.e. row1: `email@example.com`, `Bob`, `Murphy`, `1`, and then another row2 (having repeated values only except `action_id`): `email@example.com`, `Bob`, `Murphy`, `2`

Comment: I just read your discussion with Maxence, I'm updating my answer to reflect what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jay. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2507 no worries! Glad to be of help. Oh one more thing if it is still easy enough to refactor your code, I suggest you rename your `posts` `post_id` column into `facebook_id` and `users` `user_id` column into `facebook_id`. This assumes though that both `users` and `posts` records are tightly coupled to the facebook post or user. This is more "readable" and explicit, and also help anyone to easily understand your code including us upon first look of your schema, we will already know that the `post` or `user` is directly associated to facebook user or post

Comment: Actually they are two separate ID, post_id is the id of the post and user_id is the facebook user id of the user who engaged with that facebook post.

Comment: oh i see, so you `post_id` is the primary key of the `posts` table? I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Yes I am using it as my primary key and user_id as primary key for user table.

Comment: Ohh both of them are primary keys? Although only user_id corresponds to the Facebook `user_id`. I see, ok. You'd probably want to rename `user_id` into `facebook_id` maintainability-wise , so that future readers of your code (or your colleagues) would immediately understand that the primary key `facebook_id` of the `users` table is also directly associated to the Facebook user. From `posts` table, I'll also probably remove `post_id`, and just use the default `id` but create a new migration that will change the type of `id` from `:int` into `:bigint` like `change_column :posts, :id, :bigint`

Comment: Yes right. Facebook ID is more understandable. I will change the type of default ID in post table. Thanks